# A programming problem about finding max count value of [1~N] given q consecutive sequence but only using q-2

Tags: c

here is the programming problem https://acm.cs.nthu.edu.tw/problem/12673/

I have tried for days but not able to conclude a clear solving idea.

The problem in short:

> There're n sections in a line numbered from 1 to n.
>
> There're q soldiers, for i-th soldier, he can guard from section L_i to R_i(1 <= i <= q)
>
> A section is guarded if at least one soldier guard the section.
>
> You can only hire q-2 soldiers.
>
> You need to find the maximum number of sections that can be guarded by hiring q-2 soldiers from q
> soldiers.

I tried placing each soldier in the right order and count each soldier's unique guarded number, and then chose the q-2 soldiers by its unique guarded number.
But the output is not right.

here is my code with some problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct man
{
    int unique_defence_num;
    int defence_num;
    int L;
    int R;
    int id;
} man;
int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return (((man *)a)->L - ((man *)b)->L);
}
int cmpfunc2(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return (((man *)a)->unique_defence_num - ((man *)b)->unique_defence_num);
}

int main()
{
    int testcase;
    int wall, soldier;
    scanf("%d ", &testcase);
    while (testcase--)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &wall, &soldier);
        man *arr = (man *)malloc(soldier * sizeof(man));
        int i = 0, j = soldier;
        while (j--)
        { //O(soldier)
            scanf("%d %d", &(arr[i].L), &(arr[i].R));
            arr[i].defence_num = arr[i].R - arr[i].L + 1;
            arr[i].unique_defence_num = 0;
            arr[i].id = i;
            i++;
        }
        qsort(arr, soldier, sizeof(arr[0]), cmpfunc); //O(s*log(s))
        printf("the soldier id sequence after sorting on L:\t");
        for (int j = 0; j < soldier; j++)
            printf("%d ", arr[j].id);
        printf("\n");

        int *defencable = (int *)malloc(wall * sizeof(int));
        for (int j = 0; j < wall; j++)
            defencable[j] = 0;
        j = 0;
        while (j < soldier)
        { //O(s*w)
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = arr[j].L; i <= arr[j].R; i++)
            {
                if (j == 0) //first soldier
                {
                    if (i < arr[j + 1].L)
                    {
                        count++;
                        defencable[i] = 1; //the i-th gate can be guard
                    }
                }
                else if (j == soldier - 1) //last soldier
                {
                    if (i > arr[j - 1].R)
                    {
                        count++;
                        defencable[i] = 1; //the i-th gate can be guard
                    }
                }
                else if (defencable[i] == 0) // middle soldiers
                {
                    if (i > arr[j - 1].R && i < arr[j + 1].L)
                    {
                        count++;
                        defencable[i] = 1; //the i-th gate can be guard
                    }
                }
            }
            arr[j].unique_defence_num = count;
            j++;
        }
        qsort(arr, soldier, sizeof(arr[0]), cmpfunc2); //O(s*log(s))
        printf("the soldier id sequence after sorting on unique_defence_num:\t");
        for (int j = 0; j < soldier; j++)
            printf("%d ", arr[j].id);
        printf("\n");
        printf("the correspoonding unique_defence_num:\t");
        for (int j = 0; j < soldier; j++)
            printf("%d ", arr[j].unique_defence_num);
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < wall; j++)
            defencable[j] = 0;
        int max = 0;
        for (int j = 2; j < soldier; j++)
        { //exclude the first two soldier that do not contribute to the defence
            for (int i = arr[j].L; i <= arr[j].R; i++)
            {
                if (defencable[i] == 0)
                {
                    defencable[i] = 1; //the i-th gate can truely be guard
                    max++;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n\n", max);
        free(arr);
    }
}
```

the test case input:

```
3
7 5
1 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
3 5

4 3
1 1
2 2
3 4

4 4
1 1
2 2
2 3
3 4
```

the output of my code(with problem):

```
the soldier id sequence after sorting on L:     0 4 1 2 3
the soldier id sequence after sorting on unique_defence_num:    4 1 2 3 0 
the correspoonding unique_defence_num:  0 0 0 1 2
maximum defencable wall: 6

the soldier id sequence after sorting on L:     0 1 2
the soldier id sequence after sorting on unique_defence_num:    1 0 2 
the correspoonding unique_defence_num:  1 1 2
maximum defencable wall: 1

the soldier id sequence after sorting on L:     0 2 1 3
the soldier id sequence after sorting on unique_defence_num:    2 1 0 3
the correspoonding unique_defence_num:  0 0 1 2
maximum defencable wall: 2
```

and the desire output is(without debug info):

```
7
2
3
```

I have no idea how should this problem be solved and the brute force method would not work and TLE.

I think the hardest part is how to pick the 2 unwanted soldier because the 2 may be dependent to each others and may be many combinations....

(This is my first question on stack overflow, if any suggestion or reminder on problem or way of question, thanks a lots.)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm giving a general algorithm instead of the code.

I'm using the notation of `q=number of soldiers` and `n=length of wall`

Break the problem into 2 cases: One with subset and one without

**CASE A:** First iterate over every pair of soldiers and check for subsets. `(L[i]>L[j] && R[i]<R[j])`. If any subset is found, remove that soldier (should take `O(q^2)`). The problem of eliminating the other soldier becomes trivial.

**CASE B:** I'll focus my answer more on the second case where a subset isn't found.

1. Sort all soldiers based on left index in `O(qlogq)`.
2. For each soldier, calculate number of unique walls he/she is guarding (`unique_defence_num`) in `O(q*n)`.
3. Then, iterate over the sorted array of soldiers in `O(q*n + q*q)` as follows:

```
    for soldier i in 1 to q:
        for soldier j in i+1 to q:
            if(j==i+1):
                //Calculate unique positions guarded by these 2 combined in `O(n)`
            else:
                //unique positions guarded by these 2 combined = sum of both their "unique_defence_num"s (Can be found in O(1))
            update value of soldier_pair_with_least_contribution
```

4. Remove those 2 soldiers and output whatever is needed in `O(n)`

---

The key part of the algorithm: Given intervals sorted by left index (such that there are no subsets), unique combined portion can be expressed as a sum of their individual unique portions, provided at least one other line segment starts between start of these 2 line segments. This can be derived from fact that any interval starting later also finishes later.

---

Note that the greedy approach of removing one soldier and then the other soldier does not always work. Consider the 3 intervals {[1,5], [6,10], [2,9]} as an example